# Player de áudio personalizável

Tags: css

Estou desenvolvendo o front-end de um site, e preciso de um player de áudio que eu possa personalizar sem problemas, alguma dica?
De preferência que rode no IE também.

Comment: Felipe, esse tipo de pergunta não cabe bem ao formato do SO. Por favor, leia o artigo da nossa central de ajuda: [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). No entanto, você pode tentar reformular a questão acrescentando as pesquisas e algum código que você já tenha feito e pedindo uma avaliação mais objetiva do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero ajudar rs
Nesse [link](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-html5-audio-players) aqui, você encontra alguns modelos de players de áudio em HTML5, para estar se baseando no modelo.
Já a parte da personalização do player, você pode fazer utilizando jQuery, esse link [aqui](http://www.joseanmatias.com.br/mudando-o-background-da-div) dá uma ideia de como fazer isso!

Comment: Obrigado amigo, o problema do HTML é as versões anteriores do IE, tenho medo de não funcionar.

Comment: Amigo @Felipe Stoker, encontrei algo interessante que pode ajudar demais!
Veja nesse [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-all-browsers-render-html5-mark-up-correctly-even-ie6--net-8669), sabe que o formato de áudio .ogg não é suportado no IE e Safari, espero que esse método lhe auxilie.